# How to make a UICollectionView cell touchable/clickable?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, gesture

I have a UICollectionView with cells that hold images. I would like to make each individual cell of the UICollectionView touchable/clickable through code, how should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `didSelectItemAt:` delegate method.

```swift
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Attach the `dataSource` and `delegate` for the UICollectionView to your view controller class and implement that method.

In the `indexPath` parameter, you can get the position of your cell and then perform whatever action you like programmatically. Like pushing a new ViewController etc.

[This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/10/6/connecting-up-the-people) might be helpful in understanding how a UICollectionView works and how to control it from your ViewController class